# Is there a simplest way to select only the domain name from email address in oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table called **email_id**   and column name as **email_id** and I have these email id’s in the column

```
name@yahoo.com
name@msn.com
name@gmail.com
name@xmsoftware.com
```

And I need only domain names like these as **result**

```
yahoo
msn
gmail
xmsoftware
```

Is there a simplest way (or) any other function than this?

```
select substr(email_id.email_id,(instr(email_id.email_id,'@',1)+1),(instr(email_id.email_id,'.',1) - (instr(email_id.email_id,'@',1)+1))) as domain 
from email_id;
```

Comment: On a side note: Why do you want to strip the extension? Without it you are left with less than a domain name. mysite.com and mysite.uk may be two completely different things

Comment: i don't know much about real life scenarios. this was the question asked by interviewer. using instr and substr  is long so i googled ,but find no answer, i just need to know if there is any function that i am not aware of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer `REGEXP_SUBSTR`

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(email_id,'^.*@(.*)\.(.*)$',1,1,null,1) as domain 
 FROM emails;--                     ^ first match        ^ within()
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9b839374cab5ef56fe1f3e39a1a2345d)

Comment: @Rene : Thanks, it has been rectified now.

Comment: @ Kaushik  thanks for the post i didn't know that it can be done from regular expression ,which i only had little knowledge about it

Answer (score 1):

The *oldfashioned* way is to use `SUBSTR + INSTR` combination. It takes more letters to type (when compared to regular expressions), but might work faster on large data sets.

```
SQL> WITH email_id (email_id)
  2       AS (SELECT 'name@yahoo.com' FROM DUAL
  3           UNION ALL
  4           SELECT 'name@msn.com' FROM DUAL
  5           UNION ALL
  6           SELECT 'name@gmail.com' FROM DUAL
  7           UNION ALL
  8           SELECT 'name@xmsoftware.com ' FROM DUAL)
  9  select email_id,
 10         substr(email_id,
 11                instr(email_id, '@') + 1,
 12                instr(email_id, '.', instr(email_id, '@')) - instr(email_id, '@') - 1) result
 13  from email_id;

EMAIL_ID             RESULT
-------------------- --------------------
name@yahoo.com       yahoo
name@msn.com         msn
name@gmail.com       gmail
name@xmsoftware.com  xmsoftware

SQL>
```

Comment: will regular expressions create performance issues . i heard that some people say that's y it mostly not used by developers is that true or it is some what hard to understand by

Comment: For small data sets, you won't even notice the difference. For millions of rows, you might (and most probably will). If you're selecting that value for one row at a time, regular expression would be just fine.